# Debugging AngularJS web app in Firefox extensions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, angularjs, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created a Firefox extension that loads an iframe. That iframe loads a web application built using AngularJS. Is there anyway to inspect what is going on? The application loads but I have 2 input boxes that I am unable to type in.

I've developed the extension in both XUL and using the Add-On SDK and both of them don't allow me to interact with the input box. I've further noticed that when I remove the ng-model attributes, interaction works. It seems like data binding is an issue.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: are there any errors at all? does a similar basic data binding using jQuery work? My thought s that Angular mihtbe making assumptions that don't work out in the iframe it is contained in.

Comment: When I render the application in a normal window, everything works fine. It's only when I embed it in an iframe in a Firefox extension that it doesn't. The sad thing is I can't inspect elements within Firefox extensions. I wanted to try using ngModel with the "class" way but I'm not sure how.

Comment: when you say 'embed in an iframe' what do you mean? Are you injecting an iframe into content via a page-mod? Code please!

Comment: Pardon my language but basically inside my html, I have an iframe. The iframe is an AngularJS built web app.

Comment: without a simple example of this, nto sure what I can do to help.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to create a xul application, starting the application with `firefox -app application.ini -jsconsole` shows me a repeating error: `$digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` The iframe is a xul iframe and I think the window object is different then the window would be in a html page. When setting `type` of the iframe to `content-primary` and alerting the window object I get `object Window`. When it's set to `chrome` (=dangerous) I get `object chromeWindow` Both give me an error anyway though.

Comment: Looks like no amount of tweaking is going to make this one work. At line 3249 of the unminified Angularjs it tries to do a `history.replaceState` this causes an error that is nice and quietly caught by angular but after digging and digging and putting it in a try and catch I see it's causing an error: `Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)` Probably a bug since I can't find documentation that this would not be allowed. So when this bug is fixed there may be a chance of Angular working in XUL.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to say what's going wrong.  If I were running into this problem (and I've run into similar ones), I generally fall back to editing the Angular source, and adding dump (or console.log) statements to try and trace what's going on.  It's pretty terrible, but it usually gets the job done.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question is kinda old by now, but as a reference for people coming here from a web search:

you might want to look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093931/is-history-replacestate-broken-for-xul-applications-and-plugins) that lists some things that can go wrong with AngularJS inside XUL extensions, together with some solutions.